# The record cannot be inserted into the database after adding a record on the admin panel in django

Tags: python, django, web

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class NewsUnit(models.Model):
    catego = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=False)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False)
    message = models.TextField(null=False)
    pubtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    press = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from newsapp import models
import math

# Create your views here.
page1 = 1

def index(request,pageindex=None):
    global page1
    pagesize = 8
    newsall = models.NewsUnit.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    datasize = len(newsall)
    totpage = math.ceil(datasize/pagesize)
    if pageindex == None:
        page1 = 1
        newsunits = models.NewsUnit.objects.filter(enabled=True).order_by('-id')[:pagesize]
    elif pageindex == '1':
        start = (page1-2)*pagesize
        if start >= 0:
            newsunits = models.NewsUnit.objects.filter(enabled=True).order_by('-id')[start:(start+pagesize)]
            page1 -= 1
    elif pageindex == '2':
        start = page1*pagesize
        if start < datasize:
            newsunits = models.NewsUnit.objects.filter(enabled=True).order_by('-id')[start:(start+pagesize)]
            page1 += 1
    elif pageindex == '3':
        start = (page1-1)*pagesize
        if start < datasize:
            newsunits = models.NewsUnit.objects.filter(enabled=True).order_by('-id')[start:(start+pagesize)]


    currentpage = page1
    return render(request,'index.html',locals())

def detail(request, detailid=None):
    unit = models.NewsUnit.objects.get(id=detailid)
    category = unit.catego
    title = unit.title
    pubtime = unit.pubtime
    nickname = unit.nickname
    message = unit.message
    unit.press += 1  
    unit.save()  
    
    return render(request, "detail.html", locals())
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from newsapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index),
    path('index/<pageindex>/',views.index),
    path('detail/<detailid>/',views.detail),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

For this django project, I would like to insert the new record on the database list after adding a record from the admin panel. It works if I clicked save record in the admin panel but however the current new record cannot be added into the database on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/1/`. May I ask if I would like to have the record being inserted anything I am missing?

Comment: Actually, you are not saving anything in the database. Look at [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects) on how to create and save a new object in database.

Comment: I do not know which file can be used to save updated records

Comment: Could anyone provide suggested solution thanks?